# perl or sed command to find 2 strings and replace the first string with string 2

Tags: regex, shell, perl, sed

I have multiple files with below text.

Content of File 1:

```
Begin("tmp1","derived from file \"/disks/setup/ORIG_FILE1.txt\"");
```

Content of File 2:

```
Begin("tmp1","derived from file \"/disks/setup/ORIG_FILE2.txt\"");
```

Content of File 3:

```
Begin("tmp9","derived from file \"/disks/setup/ORIG_FILE4.txt\"");
```

and so on.....

Is there any command in perl or sed to find a line with "Begin" and in that line search from the first string between "..." (i.e. "tmp1" in our case) and store it in a variable then search for the last string between /..\"" i.e. (ORIG_FILE1.txt here) and store it in the variable 2 and then remove ".txt" from the variable 2 and then replace variable 1 with variable 2 and update the file.

So output files will look like:

Content of File 1:

```
Begin("ORIG_FILE1","derived from file \"/disks/setup/ORIG_FILE1.txt\"");
```

Content of File 2:

```
Begin("ORIG_FILE2","derived from file \"/disks/setup/ORIG_FILE2.txt\"");
```

Content of File 3:

```
Begin("ORIG_FILE4","derived from file \"/disks/setup/ORIG_FILE4.txt\"");
```

and so on.....

Can somebody please help me here?

Comment: What have you tried? How has it failed?

Comment: perl -pe '/^"\s+(\d+)/"=$1 "/s+\""=$2"' file..

Comment: I am very beginner to perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any sed in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ sed 's/\([^"]*"\)[^"]*\(.*\/\([^.]*\)\)/\1\3\2/' file
Begin("ORIG_FILE1","derived from file \"/disks/setup/ORIG_FILE1.txt\"");
Begin("ORIG_FILE2","derived from file \"/disks/setup/ORIG_FILE2.txt\"");
Begin("ORIG_FILE4","derived from file \"/disks/setup/ORIG_FILE4.txt\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
perl -i.bak -pe '
    if (/.*\/(.+)\.txt/) {
        $file = $1;
        s/(?<=").*?(?=")/$file/
    }
' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

That will *first* capture the "orig" file name (assuming they all have ".txt" extension), *then* replace the "tmp" placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

by gnu sed as your data in 'd',

```
 sed -E 's~^(Begin\(")\w+(".+/)(\w+)(\.\w+\\""\);)~\1\3\2\3\4~' d
```